# Javascript Bundling on visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

`System.Web.Optimization` on **Visual Studio 2013** was giving us Bundling on javascript files and the best part of that was allowing us to go with individual files or bundle them as we want. it was making debugging a joy 
now on **Visual Studio 2015** we have the grunt and Task Runner, allow me to bundle and minified but switching between bundled js and original files is just pain

is anybody has a solution to use Optimization bundling on VS 2015

Thanks

Comment: I recommend looking at brunch.it's way easier. You can do almost everything you did before. the workflow is a little bit different but you still get what you need. About the dev/prod files, when taghelpers get introduced this will be even more easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old style optimization bundling will not be available in VS2015 for ASP.NET 5.0 applications: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/134

Comment: This link provides good info too http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingfrommvc5.html

Answer (score 11):

[Edit] **BundlerMinifier Extension can do Bundling and minification as a Visual Studio Extension it has limited capabilities compare to GULP, GRUNT or My favorite WebPack  but if you want an easy solution https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier is the one**

long story short like ecm_dev said old style optimization bundling will not be available
**this is the right answer**, but it wasn't helping me to solve my bundling and minification problem and last a few months it pushed me to find replacements which were actually there
Bower, Gulp, Grunt which Microsoft is pushing us to use

I picked the Bower as a package manager 
Bower is the replacement for nuget on client files (css,js,less etc..)
and Gulp as a build task op

[gulp-bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower) Help you to pull Bower packages

[main-bower-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files) Extract Bower files in right locations

[gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) bundles your css or js files (any file)

[gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) minify your js files

[gulp-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less) compile your less files

[gulp-cssmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssmin) minify your css files

[gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) inject your css and javascript tags into your .html or .cshtml

Gulp is actually more capable than System.Web.Optimization + Web Essential combine but has lot to learn 
this may not the answer you are looking for (when I first asked this question a little longer a month ago it definitely wasn't mine)

but if you are looking for this question, you have the same problem I had 
for

enable gulp on VS 2015 : 
http://tom.cabanski.com/2014/11/23/using-gulp-with-asp-net-vnext-and-visual-studio-2015-preview/

gulp 101:
http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/07/how-to-basic-tasks-in-gulp-js/

I like to watch video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwSLFai8ovQ

and here another blog post: http://mmercan.com/blog/?p=271

Comment: How do you handle dev vs release? That is, in dev you don't want things bundled and minified, in release you do.

Comment: I create 2 HTML file with gulp.inject from single template, 1 injects all is and css files without bundle for dev and debugging, and the second file uses uglified and bundled files for release, I also do grant test on release version but not too much debugging

Comment: My solution was very similar to this one but instead of using gulp-bower and main-bower-files, I use default installer of bower and bower-installer package as a postinstall hook in .bowerrc..

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the documentation and examples provided [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html), I immediately had the same question. After the bundling and minification steps, the docs just say "Now reference the files".

I did quite a bit of research trying to find a best practice to use for conditionally referencing scripts for development and others for production. The options I like the most are:

1. Use [WireDep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) or [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) to replace placeholder values in your
   view templates with dynamically defined file references. You can choose different files to include in your gulpfile based on environment and conditionally choose whether to bundle or not. This works great for local files, but isn't so great if you want to use a CDN.
2. Use the environment tag helper to conditionally define file references. This option works great if you want to reference files from a CDN, and gives you the option to switch between local files for development and CDN files for production.

Documentation for WireDep and gulp-inject are provided in their respective links.

To use the environment tag helper, make sure your _GlobalImport view file has the following line in it.

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

Then use it like this:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/js/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/script2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/big-script-library.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="~/js/bundle/script.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.some-cdn-resource.com/big-script-library.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

The environment names correspond to the ASP.NET 5 environment variable ASPNET_ENV.

Answer (score 0):

After I complain for a whole day to Visual Studio 2015 for moving my cheese, I calmed down and just when ahead to find out how to do it the new way, I now I back to loving vs2015 :)

If you already had all your files configured, don't worry do not delete your existing configuration we will use it

1. Install Web Essentials for 2115
2. Select the files you want to bundle, if you already had the files configured and are too many only select a couple we can edit the config later
3. right-click and select "Bundle and Minifier" - "Bundle and Minify Files" (Shift-Alt-F)
4. Save the bundled in your prefeer location (maybe with a different name from the previous one, so you don't override it)
5. the first difference is that you will not see yourfile.js.bundle. Instead there is a new bundleconfig.json at your root folder
6. if you open the file you can see now you can have only one config file for all your bundles
7. Now you can copy your existing configuration from yourfile.bundle which is XML and that's ok
8. Paste into the new bundleconfig.json and just remove all the `<file> </file>` tags

and that's it... your new config is now setup

you can get more info about the new bundler here

```
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40
```

Comment: This solution is no longer correct.
Bundler and Web Compiler have been separated from the core Web Essentials plugin and will need to be installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Web Essentials 2015 Bundler and Minifier were both included in the core plugin. With Web Essentials 2015 that is no longer the case and have been seperated into its own plugin ([Plugin on Visal Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier))

Also to note, transitioning to the new plugin has you utilizing a `bundleconfig.json` file on the root of your project in lieu of the individual `.bundle` configuration files.