# Does it still make sense to use @Styles.Render and @Scripts.Render if I use bower and grunt?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gruntjs, bower, visual-studio-2015

I just had my first hour with the built in support for grunt and bower in VS 2015 an I am wondering if the the existing bundling and minification support supplied by Styles.Render and Scripts.Render together with RegisterBundles overlaps with bower / grunt.

Does it make sense to use both in conjunction or does it make more sense to just switch over to bower / grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Bundling and Minification is no longer available on ASP.NET 5, based on [this](http://www.jeffreyfritz.com/2015/05/where-did-my-asp-net-bundles-go-in-asp-net-5/) and [this SO item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664363/javascript-bundling-on-visual-studio-2015).

I suppose if you can use NPM with VS2015 on a non .NET5.0-targeted project, you could potentially use either, or even both methods. But why would you use both and create inconsistency (and possibly confusion).

Having said that, [Web Essentials 2015](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler) (VS Extension) seems to also have [its own bundling and minification option](http://madskristensen.net/post/bundling-minification-and-client-side-compilation). But I'm not sure if I'd favour this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could go either way of course, as their features are quite similar. At the moment, one benefit of `System.Web.Optimization` is that if you change a file's contents, you don't have to do anything. With Grunt/Gulp, you need to do a rebuild (unless you make it a part of your project's build steps). Another thing `System.Web.Optimization` gives you is a unique hash for the bundled files. This ensures that clients won't use a cached, outdated version of your bundle.

However, one thing to consider is that Microsoft is rebuilding ASP.NET and in that new version, Bower/Grunt/Gulp have a firm place. As far as I can tell, the new ASP.NET version by default enables bundling through Grunt/Gulp, not through some package, although it is still in beta and thus it might change.